# Putting all data from a Calender event into one row of data using Google scripts

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, calendar

I need to retrieve the list of all attendees and all emails for each calendar event on my calendar but I want all data for each event to be in one row. Currently it is giving me multiple lines for each event.

Current Output in Google Sheets:

[image: Current Output in google sheets]

Desired output in Google Sheets:

[image: Desired output in google sheets]

Below is my code:

```js
function testImportCal() {
  var sh1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Mycal12345678').getSheetByName('Calendar Import').getRange('A:I');
  sh1.clearContent();
  var mycal = 'mycal@gmail.com';
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);

  var events = cal.getEvents(new Date('November 10, 2020 00:00:00 PST'), new Date('December 20, 2020 00:00:00 PST'));

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Calendar Import');

  var header = [['Event Title', 'Event Description', 'Attendees', 'Attendees Email', 'Created By', 'Event Start', 'Event End', 'Date Created', 'Last Updated']];
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 9);
  range.setValues(header);

  function getEmailsFromArray(guestsArray) {
    var guestEmails = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < guestsArray.length; i++) {
      guestEmails.push(guestsArray[i].getEmail());
    }
    return guestEmails;
  }

  var row = 3;
  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    var myformula_placeholder = '';

    Logger.log('Event ' + i + ': ' + events[i].getId());

    var guestList = events[i].getGuestList(); //GET THE EMAIL AND STATUS OF EACH GUEST FOR EACH EVENT
    for (var d = 0; guestList != null && d < guestList.length; d++) {
      guestEmail = guestList[d].getEmail();
      guestName = guestList[d].getName();
      Logger.log('Guest ' + d + ': ' + guestList[d].getEmail());

      var details = [[events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), guestList[d].getName(), guestList[d].getEmail(), events[i].getCreators(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), events[i].getDateCreated(), events[i].getLastUpdated()]];
      var range = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 9);
      Logger.log(details);

      var range2 = sheet.getRange(row - 1, 1, 1, 9);
      range2.setValues(details);
      row++; // increment row to start the next output after the previous output
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Please share your code so we can help

Comment: Ah sorry didnt attach the code here it is.

Comment: Where is it? Make sure you edit the question and add it there

Comment: It is there now!

Comment: What do you mean by ```it is giving me multiple lines for each event```? If you could post your expected vs actual output it would be easier for us to understand what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to get all the atendees in the same cell or in the same row? And what is currently happening with your atendees, are they getting on the same row or on different rows? Thanks !

Comment: Apologies I am new at this. I have updated the question to show a current output and expected output

Answer (score 0):

You're getting it multiple times because you're using `setValues()` inside the loop that iterates over the guests, so you're adding the same event as many time as there are guests.

So you should probably move that `setValues()` to outside of the loop. In fact, you don't need to do an explicit loop if you use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
function testImportCal() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEET_ID').getSheetByName('Calendar Import');
  sheet.clearContents();
  var mycal = 'CALENDAR_ID';
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);

  var events = cal.getEvents(new Date('November 10, 2020 00:00:00 PST'), new Date('December 20, 2020 00:00:00 PST'));

  
  //var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Calendar Import');

  var header = [['Event Title', 'Event Description', 'Attendees', 'Attendees Email', 'Created By', 'Event Start', 'Event End', 'Date Created', 'Last Updated']];
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 9);
  range.setValues(header);

  function getEmailsFromArray(guestsArray) {
    var guestEmails = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < guestsArray.length; i++) {
      guestEmails.push(guestsArray[i].getEmail());
    }
    return guestEmails;
  }

  var row = 3;
  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    var myformula_placeholder = '';

    //Logger.log('Event ' + i + ': ' + events[i].getId());

    var guestList = events[i].getGuestList(); //GET THE EMAIL AND STATUS OF EACH GUEST FOR EACH EVENT
//    for (var d = 0; guestList != null && d < guestList.length; d++) {
//      guestEmail = guestList[d].getEmail();
//      guestName = guestList[d].getName();
//      Logger.log('Guest ' + d + ': ' + guestList[d].getEmail());
//
//      var details = [[events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), guestList[d].getName(), guestList[d].getEmail(), events[i].getCreators(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), events[i].getDateCreated(), events[i].getLastUpdated()]];
//      var range = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 9);
//      Logger.log(details);
//
//      var range2 = sheet.getRange(row - 1, 1, 1, 9);
//      range2.setValues(details);
//      row++; // increment row to start the next output after the previous output
//    }
    var details = [[events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getGuestList().map(guest => guest.getName()), events[i].getGuestList().map(guest => guest.getEmail()), events[i].getCreators(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), events[i].getDateCreated(), events[i].getLastUpdated()]];
    var range = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 9);
    Logger.log(details);
    
    var range2 = sheet.getRange(row - 1, 1, 1, 9);
    range2.setValues(details);
    row++; // increment row to start the next output after the previous output
  }
}
```

As a side note, there's a lot of unnecessary code there, so you might want remove it to make it easier to understand. :)

Comment: Thank you for helping! I do not know much about coding, I apologize but I am receiving a syntax error when trying to use the map(). I am using google script editor is it possible it doesnt have the ability to use this syntax?

Comment: Are you using the V8 engine? The arrow function inside the map is only supported by V8. You can enable it by clicking on the "Run" menu in the online script editor and choosing "Enable new Apps Script runtime powered by Chrome V8".

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue was that you were iterating over each guest and inserting the same event with each guest's information several times. To solve this you need to move your `details` and [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) outside the guest loop and store the guests in an array. Then, you can simply convert this array into a string with the javascript method [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) and you will get a comma separated string of the array elements.

In the following piece of code I have explained in the comments the process I took with more details (modification points are after the comment indicating them):

*Note: I have removed unnecessary lines of code you had that did not perform any specific function.*

```js
function testImportCal() {
  var sh1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEETID').getSheetByName('SHEETNAME').getRange('A:I');
  sh1.clearContent();
  var mycal = 'CALENDARID';
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);
  
  var events = cal.getEvents(new Date('November 10, 2020 00:00:00 PST'), new Date('December 20, 2020 00:00:00 PST'));
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SHEETNAME');
  
  var header = [['Event Title', 'Event Description', 'Attendees', 'Attendees Email', 'Created By', 'Event Start', 'Event End', 'Date Created', 'Last Updated']];
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 9);
  range.setValues(header);
  
  var row = 3; 
  
  //////////////////////// MODIFICATIONS ////////////////////////
  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    
    var guestList = events[i].getGuestList();
    
    // Initialise guest detail arrays to store the information of all guests
    var guestEmail=[];
    var guestName=[];
    
    //GET THE EMAIL AND STATUS OF EACH GUEST FOR EACH EVENT (no need to check if they are null with this array implementation)
    for (var d = 0;d < guestList.length; d++) {
      
      // Add the email and name to their corresponding arrays
      guestEmail.push(guestList[d].getEmail());
      guestName.push(guestList[d].getName());      
    }    
    
    // After the loop is done add the event details
    // NOTE that for the guest lists we are converting our arrays into strings which will automatically separate each element with a comma
    var details = [[events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), guestName.toString(), guestEmail.toString(), events[i].getCreators(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), events[i].getDateCreated(), events[i].getLastUpdated()]];
    var range = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 9);
    var range2 = sheet.getRange(row - 1, 1, 1, 9);
    range2.setValues(details);
    row++; // increment row to start the next output after the previous output
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much this worked and it helped me understand what was going on.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please consider accepting and/or upvoting my answer if it solved your problem. :D